# Binding data to Html tags with data received from REST API | IONIC and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

trying to build woocommerce app using rest API

Basically, i am receiving data using promise into a variable

and i have used same variable to display data to front end HTML

```
<h3 *ngIf = "onsale" style="text-align:center;font-weight: 800;margin-top:5px">Rs. {{productregprice}} / {{productonsaleprice}}</h3>
        <h3 *ngIf = "!onsale" style="text-align:center;font-weight: 800;margin-top:5px">Rs. {{productonsaleprice}}</h3>
```

the problem i am facing is - data is loaded in variable productregprice and productonsaleprice async as rest API call is finished

meanwhile on front end - HTML view is rendered and so the it gives error undefined

i am unable to understand how to wait for async call to finish and then give data to HTML tags so as to display actual price and not 0

my typescript code is

```
productregprice = 0;
    productonsaleprice = 0;
    onsale = true;
    productshortdescription =   "";

catids = this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.productid;
    secondurl = `${this.url}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/${this.catids}?consumer_key=${this.key}&consumer_secret=${this.secretkey}`;

constructor(private http: HttpClient,private route: Router) 
   {
     console.log(this.route.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.productid);
     this.product = this.getProductsData().then(res=>console.log(res));
     console.log(this.product);
     if(typeof this.product.images != 'undefined')
                    {   
                        this.productimages = this.product.images;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        this.productimages = [];
                    }
                    console.log("loaded");
   }



getProductsData()
    {
            return new Promise(resolve => {this.http.get(this.secondurl).subscribe(productdata => {resolve(productdata);});});
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Edit: use `*ngIf="product && (other conditions)"` for that HTML element.
This should be a comment but due to low reputation, adding it as an answer.
Could you please share the code where you have used `this.product` to assign values to `productregprice` and `productonsaleprice`.
You have initialized `productonsaleprice = 0` which maybe be throwing the error as you are using it in the denominator.

Comment: data is getting loaded in constructor in this.product

and on front end I am using

<h2 style="text-align:center;font-weight: 800;margin-top:5px">{{product.name}}</h2>

but I am unable to see h2 on screen due to product.name getting data async after few seconds

Comment: Just add *ngIf="product && (other conditions)" to the <h2> tag. This should work

Comment: Not working - tried with 

<h2 *ngIf="product" style="text-align:center;font-weight: 800;margin-top:5px">{{product.name}}</h2>

Comment: It would be great if you could share you code on stackblitz